# What is the derivative of $a^2$?

Tags: derivatives

My sum requires to find the derivative of $x^2+a^2$.  So derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$ but what about $a^2$? Which formula to be applied a raise to $x$ or $x$ raise to $n$?

Comment: $a^2$ is a constant (with respect to $x$)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good
question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: This is a hand-wavy way of saying it but it's **good for remembering**: since $x^0=1$ think of constants as $a^2x^0$. Now apply the power rule... Assuming $a$ is not a function of $x$

Answer (score 1):

It depends what variable you are differentiating with respect to, and whether $a$ is a constant or a variable.

---

*With respect to $x$:*

If $a$ is simply a constant, then $\frac{d(x^2+a^2)}{dx}=2x$, as the constant vanishes.

If $a$ is another variable, we use implicit differentiation: $\frac{d(x^2+a^2)}{dx}=2x+2a\frac{da}{dx}$

---

*With respect to $a$:*

We treat $x$ as a variable so again with implicit differentiation: $\frac{d(x^2+a^2)}{da}=2x\frac{dx}{da}+2a$

---

*With respect to some other variable $t$:*

Again we use implicit differentiation so: $\frac{d(x^2+a^2)}{dt}=2x\frac{dx}{dt}+2a\frac{da}{dt}$